# Elementos NaN en red neuronal

Tags: python-3.x, array, arraylist, numpy, redes-neuronales

Hola tengo una duda y espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy creando una red neuronal sencilla para clasificar (de 3 capas en total, una de entrada, otra escondida y la de salida), mi matriz de datos es inputs y su clasificación es outputs.
A la hora de implementar el Backpropagation me genera el siguiente error: "Dot product shape mismatch (4, 617) vs (454, 3), el cual proviene de "self.delta_1w" y es justamente porque se agregaron 163 elementos en "self.error", cosa que no entiendo porque y los cuales parece ser que son puros "NaN". No entiendo porque pasa esto si no estoy alterando el "self.error".

[image: N]
[image]

class NeuralNetwork:

```
 #X*W
def __init__(self, inputs, outputs):
    self.inputs  = inputs                                    #454x3
    self.outputs = outputs                                   #454x1
    self.weights_1 = np.random.rand(self.inputs.shape[1],4)  #3x4
    self.bios_1 = np.random.rand(self.inputs.shape[0],4)     #454x4
    self.weigths_2 = np.random.rand(4,1)                     #4x1
    self.bios_2= np.random.rand(self.inputs.shape[0],1)      #454x1


def sigmoid(self, x, deriv=False): #función de activación
    if deriv == True:
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def l2_cost(self, outputs, hidden_2,deriv=True): #error cuadrático medio y su derivada
    if deriv==True:
        return (outputs-hidden_2)
    return np.mean(outputs-hidden_2)**2

def feed_forward(self):
    self.hidden_1 = self.sigmoid(self.inputs@self.weights_1 + self.bios_1) #454x4   a_{1}=f(Xw_{1} + b_{1})
    self.hidden_2 = self.sigmoid(self.hidden_1@self.weigths_2 + self.bios_2) #454x1 a_{2}=f(a_{1}w_{2} + b_{2})


def backpropagation(self):
    self.error    = self.l2_cost(self.outputs,self.hidden_2,deriv=True) #454x1 derivada del coste
    print(self.error)

    self.delta_2b = self.error*self.sigmoid(self.hidden_2, deriv=True) #454x1
    self.delta_1b = self.delta_2b@self.weigths_2.T*self.sigmoid(self.hidden_1,deriv=True)# 454x4
    print(self.delta_1b.shape)
    self.delta_2w = self.hidden_1.T@(self.error*self.sigmoid(self.hidden_2, deriv=True)) #4x1
    self.delta_1w = self.inputs.T@(self.sigmoid(self.hidden_1)@(self.delta_2w@self.weigths_2.T)) #3x4

    #Actualizar los pesos y bios
    self.weights_1 -= 0.05*self.delta_1w
    self.weigths_2 -= 0.05*self.delta_2w
    self.bios_1    -=0.05*self.delta_1b
    self.bios_2    -=0.05*self.delta_2b

def train(self, epochs=2):
    for epoch in range(epochs):

        self.feed_forward()
        self.backpropagation()
```